# Unable to launch browser: "spawn C:\Program Files\Google\Application\chrome.exe ENOENT"

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

Just making a simple HTML, CSS and JavaScript web app in Visual Studio code.
Trying to run and debug so I can test it in the browser (Chrome).
It automatically made a launch.json file for me - the default config didn't work so I changed the route to this: "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html" - thinking all would be fixed!

Now I'm getting a completely different error:

Unable to launch browser: "spawn C:\Program Files\Google\Application\chrome.exe ENOENT"

Tried changing JSON file configuration.
Checked where chrome was installed - file location matches.

Was expecting the file to be debugged and index.html to open in my Chrome browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9LLk.png)

Comment: Try wrapping the path in quotes. If that doesn't help, check inside the Task Manager where chrome.exe is located when you run it - for me it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.